# Is it safe to use ssh module to authenticate user of my application locally?

Tags: python, authentication

I currently need to create an authentication wall for an office application, which would use the user credentials on the machine.
so I created the below quick script:

```
from pexpect import pxssh

from pexpect import pxssh
def can_login(host="127.0.0.1",username=None, password=None):
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    if not s.login (host,username, password):
        print("SSH session failed on login.")
        print(str(s))
    else:
        print("SSH session login successful")
       
        s.logout()
```

Which is a snippet from an answer to a similar question which I can't find the URL to.
Is this safe? to do this? Is there a better way to achieve the same without any possible security risks?

Comment: Is this on a *nix system or Windows? Maybe you'd be better using a PAM authenticator like [python-pam](https://pypi.org/project/python-pam/), if you're on a Linux system, for instance.

Comment: You have root (or privileged access): you can check any account's password for validity
You don't have root: you can only check the validity of the username running the tool

Comment: The code posted above can actually be run without any root permission